# How to use PacketLogger to analyze Bluetooth packets?

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've recently downloaded PacketLogger (an additional tool for Xcode) from the Apple Developers' platform. As you may know, this tool is useful for dumping traffic on the Bluetooth interface of an iMac, for instance. However, I don't manage to use the "Analyze" and "Inspector" windows that are made to deeply decode a Bluetooth  packet.

So does anyone can help me with this PacketLogger software please ?

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the "Analyze" and "Inspector" windows in the current version of PacketLogger do nothing and are simply there because this is old partially abandoned software from Apple.  The main view of PacketLogger seems to breakdown the meaning of Bluetooth packets in a pretty detailed way.  Just a guess though.

For deeper analysis, you can export PacketLogger captures in the btsnoop format and open them up with WireShark.

Comment: Or you can often just open PacketLogger captures with Wireshark directly.